# Performance testing: YSlow on Firefox 37

Tags: firefox, performance-testing, yslow

YSlow by Yahoo is a great performance testing tool, especially in Firefox (FF) where it is integrated with Firebug, but unfortunately it is no longer working in the latest versions of FF. Basically, the links and buttons in the app are no longer responsive. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/issues/142), but I haven't come across any fix to it.

*Does anybody out there have an idea on how to make this tool work again in the **current** version of FF (v.37)?*

I don't want to downgrade FF to make this work. I also realise I could test in other browsers, but I prefer to use FF.

P.S. No, the YSlow project is [not dead](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/exceptional-performance/conversations/topics/2094), although there haven't been any recent updates.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too. By changing its setting it works but only it's Analyzing part and not the links and buttons in the app

1. Go to Add-ons (about:addons)
2. Click on Options button of YSlow
3. Select Automatically run YSlow when page finishes loading

Comment: This is probably the closest to an answer we're gonna get until they fix the FF bug. I can't accept it, but +1 for the effort and the partial answer. P.S. sorry about the late reply.

Comment: It's okay. Unfortunately I didn't find another solution. you're right, we should wait for FF fix.It's okay. You're right. Unfortunately